# split function not working properly for simulated data?

Tags: r, error-handling, split, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I simulated some data which I wanted to split into a list of data based on `id` but it seems that the `split()` function is not working properly?

```
set.seed(323)
#simulate some data
tsfunc2 <- function () {
  x1 = rnorm(25, mean = 3, sd = 1) 
  x2.sample = rnorm(5, mean = 2, sd = 0.5) 
  x2 = rep(x2.sample, each = 5)
  mu = rnorm(25, mean = 10, sd = 2) 
  y=as.numeric(mu + x1 + x2)
  data.frame(id=rep(1:5, each=5), time=1:5, x1=x1, x2=x2, y=y)
}

set.seed(63)
#create a dataset in which the simulated data are randomly sampled in order to create imbalanced panel data 
fd <- function() {
  df <- tsfunc2()[sample(nrow(tsfunc2()), 20), ]
  ds <- df[with(df, order(id, time)),]
  return(ds)
}

set.seed(124)
split(fd(), fd()$id) #it seems that data are not properly split based on id (e.g., the first row of id2)
$`1`
  id time       x1       x2        y
1  1    1 1.614929 1.900059 13.43994
3  1    3 2.236970 1.900059 14.49136
4  1    4 3.212306 1.900059 15.08736

$`2`
  id time       x1       x2        y
5  1    5 4.425538 1.900059 15.53696 #this row is supposed to be in id1
7  2    2 3.700229 2.027456 17.48522
8  2    3 2.770645 2.027456 15.20741
9  2    4 3.197094 2.027456 13.44979

$`3`
   id time       x1       x2        y
12  3    2 1.576201 1.658917 16.40684
13  3    3 2.594909 1.658917 14.34763
14  3    4 3.995387 1.658917 16.36730
15  3    5 3.958818 1.658917 15.37498

$`4`
   id time       x1       x2        y
16  4    1 3.918088 1.636148 15.48205
17  4    2 2.849030 1.636148 12.52288
18  4    3 1.776931 1.636148 12.54456
19  4    4 2.131176 1.636148 13.63235
20  4    5 1.957515 1.636148 15.55745

$`5`
   id time       x1       x2        y
21  5    1 1.896362 1.569048 12.54131
22  5    2 3.444185 1.569048 14.56303
23  5    3 2.795049 1.569048 12.67120
25  5    5 2.868678 1.569048 13.88765
```

Comment: The function `fd()` includes `sample` to randomly sample data. Every time you call the function `fd()` you will get different results; sometimes 4 or 5 rows for `id` of 1, for example. If you call `fd()` once, such as `seed.fd <- fd()`, you can then try `split(seed.fd, seed.fd$id)` to get the outcome you may be looking for. Calling `set.seed` before this will also give you reproducible results.

Comment: Thanks @Ben. That's indeed the problem.

Comment: just ensure you use `~id` instead of `fd()$id`. eg `split(fd(), ~id)`

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you for the alternative. I got this error though: `Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors`